# Error MPI: make: *** [Makefile:232: obj/parallel_tools.o] Error 1

Tags: gcc, installation, fortran, openmpi

I am trying to install a code called Tomofast-x (written in Fortran) available in GitHub:
https://github.com/TOMOFAST/Tomofast-x

I am using Ubuntu LTS 22.04 in a Virtual Machine to install it.

The code manual says:

To compile the code you need: GCC (version 4.9 or newer) or Intel compiler, and the MPI library (such as OpenMPI).

The makefile is contained in the root folder and should be used to compile Tomofast-x. Compiling the code is a necessary step to be able to run inversions.
To compile the code run the make command in the code directory as:

`make`

I am stuck in this make command.

I cloned the repository from GitHub and inside the Tomofast-x directory, I typed the command make and it appeared on the terminal:
Edit: the wrapper compiler error is ok now, but a new error is appearing. Is this related to the source code or with OpenMPI?

```
/git-repos/Tomofast-x$ make

mpif90 -std=gnu -fimplicit-none -frange-check -fconvert=big-endian -O3 -fmax-errors=10 -pedantic -pedantic-errors -Waliasing -Wampersand -Wcharacter-truncation -Wline-truncation -Wsurprising -Wno-tabs -Wunderflow -DUSE_FLUSH6 -J obj -o obj/parallel_tools.o -c ./src/utils/parallel_tools.f90
./src/utils/parallel_tools.f90:207:21:

  204 |     call MPI_Gatherv(MPI_IN_PLACE, nelements, CUSTOM_MPI_TYPE, &
      |                     2
......
  207 |     call MPI_Gatherv(array, nelements, CUSTOM_MPI_TYPE, &
      |                     1
Error: Type mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (REAL(8)/INTEGER(4)).
./src/utils/parallel_tools.f90:168:21:

  168 |     call MPI_Gatherv(val, nelements, CUSTOM_MPI_TYPE, &
      |                     1
......
  204 |     call MPI_Gatherv(MPI_IN_PLACE, nelements, CUSTOM_MPI_TYPE, &
      |                     2
Error: Type mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (REAL(8)/INTEGER(4)).
make: *** [Makefile:232: obj/parallel_tools.o] Error 1
```

I installed GCC using:

```
sudo apt update
install build-essential
```

gcc version is 11.2.0

Edit: change the way of installing OpenMPI, now I am using:
  `./configure -prefix=/usr/local/openmpi CXX=g++ CC=gcc FC=gfortran F90=gfortran F77=gfortran`

I can compile .f90 codes using mpifort, e.g. `mpifort hello_world_mpi.f90 -o hello_world_mpi` and successfully run the compiled code.

I installed OpenMPI using the tutorial available at:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QW405eKWQdQ&t=194s

Can someone tell me how can I resolve this issue and get over with the installation? I am new to CS and I have no clue about the error mentioned above.

Comment: What haooens when you comoile some MPI hello world program using `mpif90`? Which MPI library version did you install?

Comment: OpenMPI is available by apt get in ubuntu - did you try that?

Comment: @IanBush, I already have installed OpenMPI extracting the download file in their website.
@VladimirFГероямслава, Thank you for the tip. I reinstalled OpenMPI using a different command (see my edit). I can compile .f90 codes and run them using `mpirun` e.g.`mpirun -np 1 hello-world`. I edited my question, since another issue has risen in the `make` command.

Comment: Why do you configure with gcc, g++ and gfortran and not with mpicc, mpic++ and mpif90?

Comment: As I said, I followed the youtube tutorial. I am new in CS. How I should type the ./configure arguments then? Where should I insert the `-fallow-argument-mismatch` (in the similar question you answered this)? I installed GCC-9, but different errors appeared.